# Scroll the page when the user's mouse reaches the top/bottom of the page

Tags: javascript, scroll, drag-and-drop

I'm trying to create drag-and-drop and I want my window to be scrolled in case I start the drag and reach the top / bottom of my page until I come out of the top/bottom "zone". So far what I have written works differently and I can't figure out a way to make it work the way I want. 
Is there any way to do so using vanilla JS?

```js
let mouseDown = true;

function mousedown() {
  mouseDown = true;
}

function mouseup() {
  mouseDown = false;
}
if (!document.querySelector(".arrow-timeline")) {
  this.element.addEventListener('mousemove', function() {
    let x, y;

    function handleMouse(e) {
      // Verify that x and y already have some value
      if (x && y && mouseDown) {
        // Scroll window by difference between current and previous positions
        window.scrollBy(e.clientX - x, e.clientY - y);
      }
      // Store current position
      x = e.clientX;
      y = e.clientY;
    }
    // Assign handleMouse to mouse movement events
    document.onmousedown = mousedown;
    document.onmousemove = handleMouse;
    document.onmouseup = mouseup;
  })
}
```

Comment: I made you a snippet. Please add relevant HTML to make it a [mcve]

Comment: Why do you have all the event handler assignments inside the mousemove handler?